# ruby script with command spawns a DOS shell instead of a msysgit one

Tags: ruby, msysgit

I've installed the latest Git Bash (msysgit). If I create a simple ruby file named test.rb with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts `dir`
puts `ls -al`
```

Running `ruby test.rb` will print the directory on the first `puts` but fail to find `ls` on the second `puts`. It is obviously spawning a DOS shell instead of a msysgit shell.

How can I specify that child processes should run under a msysgit shell?

Also, the child shell should inherit the environment variables (specially PATH) from the calling shell.

Comment: The [**childprocess** gem](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/jarib/childprocess) might help you spawn a process of a custom type. One example from the docs: `process = ChildProcess.build("ruby", "-e", "sleep")`

Comment: The only thing missing might be the PATH to the msys utilities. Does it work if you change `ls` to the absolute path to the `ls.exe` program?

Comment: @Nick: It spawns a CMD shell so it would work if I were to call the ls.exe with its explicit path. However I'm using `ls` as an example here. I need to execute rake and ruby commands and those rely on settings from the bash .bash_profile and .profile. I would hate to have to duplicate those as Windows environment variables. Multiple machines would have to be maintained in our landscape.

Comment: Yep - was really just suggesting that as a test to see if it's the path that's the problem, rather than as an actual solution.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I had a look at the src for the childprocess gem. It's using Windows CreateProcess() underneath so I suspect that it would not pick up the bash settings. Beside, it would really make the code much harder to read than simply using backticks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just learned to that you can use backticks or system in ruby to run shell commands, pretty nice.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm There's much more. See here https://makandracards.com/makandra/1243-execution-of-shell-code-in-ruby-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as of writing is that it isn't possible. A spawn process in msysgit is a CMD process. We can however make the CMD process call a ruby script to work around this limitation.